# XSLT assign a space as value

Tags: xslt, if-statement

I am looking for replace null values with space if any in given loop .

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($rowData)/cell">
   <td align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{$startingId + position() - 1}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value">
      </xsl:value-of>
   </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Loop is within template 
Here @value is fetching value from a varicable

If @value do not holds any data alignment of table is being disturbed so I thought replacing null with `&nbsp;` can help me.

Sagar Makhesana

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null value" in the XSLT/XPath data model, so it's not at all clear what your actual requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use CSS in your HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
table { empty-cells: show; }
</style>
```

Put that in the `head` section of your HTML.

Comment: Hello Martin,

I tried same thing it does not work. And you get it exactly i just wanted to show Empty cells as well even if there are no data for that particular cell.

Comment: Make sure you force IE into standards compliant mode by generating a DOCTYPE that does that, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#docmode. As you generate your HTML with XSLT, you might need to use `<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, and I am mostly guessing. It sounds like instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@value">
</xsl:value-of>
```

you want to be using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
<xsl:if test="not(string(@value))">&#160;</xsl:if>
```

That's if the exercise is really necessary at all - as pointed out by Martin Honnen.